# How to do this integral analytically to get the form of result showed up below?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How to do this integral below analytically?
$$\frac{1}{T_s}\int_{0}^{T_s}{\rm exp}(j2\pi(f_k-f_l)t){\rm d}t$$
One of the forms showed in my textbook is 
$${\rm exp}(j\pi(f_k-f_l)T_s)\frac{\sin (\pi(f_k-f_l)T_s)}{\pi(f_k-f_l)T_s}$$
How to get the result above analytically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important equality is
$$
\sin(aT)=\frac{\exp(ajT)-\exp(-ajT)}{2j}.
$$
Integrating,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^T\exp(2ajt)\,dt&=\Bigl[\frac{\exp(2ajt)}{2aj}\Bigr]_0^T=\frac{1}{2aj}\bigl(\exp(2ajT)-1\bigr)\\
&=\exp(ajT)\frac{\exp(ajT)-\exp(-ajT)}{2aj}\\
&=\exp(ajT)\frac{\sin(aT)}{a}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Now, divide by $T$ and insert your value $a=\pi(f_k-f_l)$. I also wrote $T$ instead of $T_s$.